# How to run the task sequentially?

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I have two functions in a sequential class set, say

@task
def fun_1(self):

```
print("Post Request")
```

@task
def fun_2(self):
print("GET Request")

now if I run it as with user 1 and ramp up 1 then it will run sequentially. no issues in that.
But when I define user like 2 and ramp up say 1 then it will run it like this

2 times fun_1 first then
2 times fun_2

I need to execute it like :
fun_1
fun_2
fun_1
fun_2

How to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. The sequence you might be seeing User1.fun_1, User2.fun_1, User1.fun_2, User2.fun_2.
https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/tasksets.html#sequentialtaskset-class
The note at the bottom recommends that sometimes it's easier to do the user flow in one task.

```
@task
def fun_1(self):
  print("Post Request")
  print("Get Request")
```